# Arranging files in a folder Mac?

Tags: macos

Im running Mac OS X Lion 10.8.2 and every time I boot up and go to my Applications folder the apps are all over the place, I proceed by arranging them alphabetically but later they are all over the place once again. Any ideas on what could be happening or why?

Comment: Can you try running `sudo rm /Applications/.DS_Store` from a Terminal? If that doesn't help, please add more details: Does it only happen to the Applications folder or all? Or just a few? Does the issue persist when you reboot? Does it happen when you log into another user account (create one and test if possible)?

Comment: @slhck Been trying to test but lately I havent had problems as soon as they persist I will try remove the DS_Store file and see if it fixes the problem. Cheers